# Recursion: base case vs. small version

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures

I'm reviewing the definition of recursion and in my notes are two questions about a recursive problem. One question asks about the **base case**, the other one about the **small version** of the problem, I always get confused about which is which... can you help me to find a way to better understand these concepts?

The examples in the exercise are:

- a function that determines if there is a "x" element in an array
- a function that determines if the string is palindrome or not

for both:

1. Find the base case
2. Find the small version of the problem
3. (Implement the recursive solution)

Comment: I am going to recommend posting this question at http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Base case

This is a trivial case where the recursion ends. (think about an **input** case) E.g.

1. If a string is empty it contains obviously no 'x'
2. if a string has non or one character, this string is a palindrome.

Notice: some times there is more than one base case: E.g. the fibonacci-numbers have two base cases (the first and the second number).

#### Small version

Here you want to find a small step, where you can go on. (think about a simple **action** to perform on an input)

1. A string contains a 'x', if the first character is a 'x' or the rest of the string contains a 'x'.
2. A string is a palindrome, if the first and the last character are equal and the string between is also a palindrome.